# Gstreamer mpegtsmux not forwarding stream_start event

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I am trying to play an MP4 file with my custom pipeline. I have a `h264parse` for the video and an aac parse for the audio, both of which go into a mpegtsmux (because i need the output to be in the transport stream format to play it). The issue that I am facing is: when I connect both the `h264parse` and `aacparse` to the `mpegtsmux`, the events (like caps event, stream-start, etc) do not get forwarded to my sink. When I try with just one of the two connected to the `mpegtsmux`, it works fine, and plays video or audio, based on which component I connect. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by introducing two queues:

1.) between the qtdemux and the h264parse

2.) between the qtdemux and the aacparse